# Generate upper and lower password case password from hash

Tags: python, security, hash, passwords

I am implementing a password generator, which creates passwords based on the service name and a master password. For this the master password and service are hashed. Now I only have lowercase letters and numbers. How could I also include uppercase letters and special symbols?

I found following code, which seems to solve the problem. Should I use it and what exactly does it do?

```
raw_hexdigest = make_password(plaintext, service)

# Convert the hexdigest into decimal
num = int(raw_hexdigest, 16)

# What base will we convert `num` into?
num_chars = len(alphabet)

# Build up the new password one "digit" at a time,
# up to a certain length
chars = []
while len(chars) < length:
    num, idx = divmod(num, num_chars)
    chars.append(alphabet[idx])

return ''.join(chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the hashed password is returned as an integer key.  The password you return is simply that integer expressed in some base, with a given `alphabet`.  The crux of this is the `alphabet` you supply.

For base 10, the alphabet is "01234356789"; for hexadecimal, it's "01234356789ABCDEF".  It seems that you have been using base 36: 10 digits and 26 lower-case letters.

To expand this, simply assign `alphabet` to be the characters you want in your passwords.

in more detail, the loop at the bottom is a digit-by-digit base conversion.  The `base` is the length of the alphabet.  At each iteration, the loop uses `divmod` to split the pass-key integer into a "units" value in that base (`idx`) and the quotient, the rest of the integer.  Then it picks the corresponding character from the alphabet and appends it to a string that eventually becomes the password.

I suggest that you insert a few strategic `print` statements and watch how this runs ... perhaps in base 10, then 16.  Instead of calling `make_password`, just set the key to something you recognize well, such as

```
raw_hexdigest = 1024 + 256 + 4 + 1
```

From there, watch how this number gets handled in various alphabets you give the routine.